# mod_rewrite for 2 same files in different folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have files:

```
search_result.php
new/search_result.php
```

mod_rewrite URL for these files are

```
www.domain.com/search?q=
www.domain.com/new/search?q=
```

The first one is working fine. But when I open `www.domain.com/new/search?q=`, its picking the file `search_result.php` in the root folder, I want it to pick the file `new/search_result.php`

The mod_rewrite code I'm using for both the folders is:

```
RewriteRule ^search$ search_result.php [QSA,L]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: who voted -ve to my question? If you think its a nonsense questions, then get me the solution before you vote it down. Nonsense people!!

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule should be like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)?search/?$ /$1search_result.php [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: I have got 2 htaccess files, 1 in root folder and 2 in "new" folder. Shall I put it only in the root folder and it will work for both the folders?

Comment: Yes put it in root, it will work for both. Make sure there is no conflicting rule in new/.htaccess

Comment: it didnt work. If I put it only in root folder, the root folder file is working fine but the new folder file returns 404. But if I put it in both the folder, the new folder file points to the root folder file.

Comment: Most likely there is a conflict because of the your existing rules. Can you dump both .htaccess in your question for investigation.

Comment: May be you can answer my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364027/mod-rewrite-for-query-string